# Why delegate is not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, delegation

My delegate:

```
@class UpdateUserSummary;
@protocol UpdateSummaryDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)updateSummaryDidCancel:(UpdateUserSummary*)controller;
- (void)updateSummaryDone:(UpdateUserSummary*)controller;

@end
```

at interface :

```
@interface UpdateUserSummary : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<UpdateSummaryDelegate> delegate;
@end


- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate updateSummaryDidCancel:self];
}
```

Response from delegate:

```
-(void)updateSummaryDidCancel:(UpdateUserSummary *)controller
{
    // just close modal vc
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Comment: You need to clarify what exactly your problem is, the code you posted doesn't explain it.

Comment: have you set UpdateUserSummary.delegate = self @ your class that implement UpdateSummaryDelegate protocol?

Comment: yes ,, at the previous it was working fine , when i added new view controller i got this issue , but i undo all of what i do but nothing done

Comment: One UpdateUserSummary object can set it's delegate only for one implementer at a time, workaround would be to declare delegate1, delegate2, etc fi several view controllers are sharing it

Comment: @CalinChitu , you are right ,, what can i do to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@protocol MUpdateSummaryDelegate;

@interface MUpdateSummary : NSObject

@property (assign) id<UpdateSummaryDelegate> delegate; //You need this

@end


@protocol UpdateSummaryDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)updateSummaryDidCancel:(UpdateUserSummary *)controller;

@end
```

In the class where you are calling delegate, you need to set delegate.

```
MUpdateSummary *mUpdateSummary = [[MUpdateSummary alloc] init];
mUpdateSummary.delegate = self;
```

Comment: is this what you mean ?
interface UpdateUserSummary : UIViewController @property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate; end

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender { [self.delegate updateSummaryDidCancel:self]; }

Comment: make sure you set your delegate property in the class where you call delegate method. "mUpdateSummary.delegate = self;"

Comment: '@interface DEMOSecondViewController ()<UpdateSummaryDelegate>'

'-(void)updateSummaryDidCancel:(UpdateUserSummary *)controller'
'{'
    '// just close modal vc'
    '[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];'
'}'

Answer (score 2):

Use this,
UpdateUserSummary.delegate = self;
where you are calling delegate in you implementation class.

Comment: is this what you mean ?
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
        [self.delegate updateSummaryDidCancel:self];
    }

Comment: I think you got the solution.

Comment: Please refer formal protocol.